# How to call a function every time Django restarts?

Tags: python, django, celery, gunicorn, wsgi

I have a Django webservice that is hosted using Gunicorn in production. I need to call the function `restart_event` every time the webservice is restarted. This is the pseudo code of the function

```
def restart_event():
    """This function should be called everytime Django restarts"""

    # read list of registered companies from the database
    companies = Company.objects.all()

    for company in companies:
        # perform various operations on the data
        business_logic1(company)
        business_logic2(company)
        change_celery_settings()
```

How do configure Django such that the above function is called every time Django restarts? Note that since Gunicorn is being used I won't be doing a `python manage.py runserver` rather I will be starting and stopping the Gunicorn webserver

Comment: What exactly do you consider a restart, taking into account that gunicorn can create and drop worker processes at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call code every time Django starts, you can do it within an app config by overriding its ready function.
E.g.

```py
class FooConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        # read list of registered companies from the database
        companies = Company.objects.all()

        for company in companies:
            # perform various operations on the data
            business_logic1(company)
            business_logic2(company)
            change_celery_settings()
```

More information on this can be found [over in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)